# Error - msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I'm trying to install Sitecore 9 Update 1 but getting the following error:

```
[---------------------------------------------- InstallWDP : WebDeploy -----------------------------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Info: Adding MsDeploy.Site (MsDeploy.Site).
Info: Adding database (user id=sa;data source=INBASDLP05243;initial catalog=sc901demo_Processing.Pools)
Info: Initializing deployment: Pending.
Info: Analyzing deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Updating database: Pending.
Info: Creating deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Deploying package to database: Pending.
Info: Creating deployment plan: Running.
Info: Initializing deployment: Running.
Info: Initializing deployment (Start)
Info: Initializing deployment: Faulted.
Info: Initializing deployment (Failed)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Deploying package to database: Faulted.
Error: Could not read schema model header information from package.
Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHODError: The model version '2.9' is not supported.

Error count: 1.
More Information: Could not read schema model header information from package.
The model version '2.9' is not supported.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero
exit code - (-1)
At D:\SITECORE9\Sitecore901install.ps1:42 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:22
Transcript stopped, output file is D:\SITECORE9\xconnect-xp0.190405.log
Invoke-CommandTask : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code -
(-1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-WebDeployTask.ps1:36
char:2
+     Invoke-CommandTask -Path $Path -Arguments $msdeployArgs -TaskName ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask
```

[image: WebDeploy Error]

I have used SIF 1.2.1 to install Sitecore 9.0.1. Not sure why this error is appearing or i have missed something. If somebody could help me on this it will be very helpful since i'm not able to find any clue on this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did not install required "**Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DAC Fx)**" version 2016.

You can download it from here:
https://www.microsoft.com/enus/download/details.aspx?id=53013

See chapter "Prerequisites for using the Sitecore Installation Framework" of installation guide for more information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But i have installed the DACFx 2016 in my machine. But still getting below error. I'm not able to attach screenshot in comments and full error message.  
Warning: A project which specifies SQL Server 2016 as the target platform may experience compatibility issues with SQL Server 2012.Warning: The database containment option has been changed to None.  This may result in deployment failure if the state of the database is not compliant with this containment level.
Error: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:You can only create a user with a password in a contained database.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server 2012? As I know It is not supported on sitecore 9. Just upgrade it and make sure to complete all of prerequisites before installation (data-tier, script dom, contained database etc.).

Comment: It requires SQL 2016 Service Pack 1, ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, and Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for Sql Server. Make sure all those are installed.